# At what point are child views attached to the parent view

Tags: android

I created a custom layout which can have an arbitrary amount of child views.
I figured out that the child views are not available when I try to access them in the constructor of my layout view.
So what I currently do is to access them in onMeassure, but it seems to be a bad idea, since this gets called several times.
What is the best place in my layout to init child views? I wish there was a method like `onChildViewsAttached()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Child views are attached to the parent once layout pass is finished, i.e `layout()` of the view group is finished.

You can also register `OnGlobalLayoutListener` or `OnPredrawListener`on the `ViewTreeObserver` of your custom layout.

Comment: I am overriding a relative layout. I don't think I should need a layoutListener in this case. Also measuring is done before layouting, so I don't think your answer is correct. Or maybe I got it wrong. Fact is that the childviews are accessible in the onMeasure method.